# response dot length doesn't happen to be working

Tags: javascript

When I do

```
 console.log(response.data.rates)
```

I am getting response like this

```
{AUD: 1.3804, BGN: 1.6664, BRL: 4.0884, CAD: 1.2962, CHF: 0.9686, …}
```

Now, I want to run `for loop` till the `.length` of element.

but before that I did `console.log(response.data.rates.length)` which is coming out to be **undefined**.

**[Question:]** What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: `response.data.rates` is an object not an array. It cannot be iterated that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object does not have a length. What you need is the length of an array. Use `Object.keys(response.data.rates).length` to get the length of the keys of the object.

Here is an example:

```js
var response = {
   data: {
      rates: {AUD: 1.3804, BGN: 1.6664, BRL: 4.0884, CAD: 1.2962, CHF: 0.9686}
   }
};

var keys = Object.keys(response.data.rates);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
   console.log(keys[i], response.data.rates[keys[i]]);
}

// or without length, but with a forEach loop:
console.log('---');

Object.keys(response.data.rates).forEach(key => {
   console.log(key, response.data.rates[key]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

its an object, `length` property is for `arrays` in javascript

you can use `Object.keys()` to iterate over an object [[link]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 0):

Object doesn't have length property

use

```
Object.keys()
```